# tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier() causes app to hang

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2, ios9

**ORIGINAL POST**

We have recently converted our app to Swift 2.0, and iOS9.  One strange issue I am seeing is that calls to tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier() cause the app to hang in the simulator.

---

The code

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    //hangs on the line below
    let headersection: HeaderSectionCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SectionHeader") as! HeaderSectionCell 

    ...

    return headersection
}
```

The header cell

```
class HeaderSectionCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var labelOne: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet var labelTwo: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet var textView: UITextView!

}
```

---

The simulator CPU usage pegs at 100%

[image: CPU Pegging]

---

After hitting pause in Xcode, it shows me its hanging on this Swift function.

[image: Pausing while hanging shows us here]

---

Here are some of the routines where iOS is looping under the covers.

[image]

[image]

Finally, our Swift call to dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier()
[image]

This particular hanging instance is from the function `tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int)`, but we're also hanging inside of a call to `tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)`, with the same issue.

I've tried playing around with the cell properties in storyboard editor, but nothing sticks out as anything different from other views that are working fine.

**EDIT**

It appears that there is an infinite loop between Foundation and libobjc.A.dylib, underneath that call to dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier().  I ended up making sure Foundation was imported before any other framework, and abstracted the offending UITableViewCell into its own class (was being reused).  The original call in question is now working, but there is another one that is still looping under the Swift covers that I am working to figure out.

Hitting pause in the infinite loop puts me in the same assembly stack locations:

Top of stack trace after pause:

```
libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend:
    0x107f6a800 <+0>:   testq  %rdi, %rdi
    0x107f6a803 <+3>:   jle    0x107f6a850               ; <+80>
    0x107f6a805 <+5>:   movq   (%rdi), %r11
    0x107f6a808 <+8>:   movq   %rsi, %r10
    0x107f6a80b <+11>:  andl   0x18(%r11), %r10d
    0x107f6a80f <+15>:  shlq   $0x4, %r10
    0x107f6a813 <+19>:  addq   0x10(%r11), %r10
    0x107f6a817 <+23>:  cmpq   (%r10), %rsi
    0x107f6a81a <+26>:  jne    0x107f6a820               ; <+32>
->  0x107f6a81c <+28>:  jmpq   *0x8(%r10)
```

Top of stack trace after another pause:

```
Foundation`-[NSLocalizableString length]:
    0x1071c5cbc <+0>:  pushq  %rbp
    0x1071c5cbd <+1>:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
->  0x1071c5cc0 <+4>:  movq   0x80461(%rip), %rax       ; NSLocalizableString._developmentLanguageString
    0x1071c5cc7 <+11>: movq   (%rdi,%rax), %rdi
    0x1071c5ccb <+15>: movq   0x7436e(%rip), %rsi       ; "length"
    0x1071c5cd2 <+22>: popq   %rbp
    0x1071c5cd3 <+23>: jmpq   *0x8ea77(%rip)            ; (void *)0x0000000107f6a800: objc_msgSend
```

It's just looping back and forth between these two lower level routines, consuming 100% of the simulator CPU.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It was a String localization issue.  The UITableViewCell contained UITextField with a non-empty value for the Text property, that didn't have English checked in the Localization properties of the UITextView.

Checking `English` fixed the issue.

What a pain!  Go figure, why not infinitely loop instead of throw an intelligible error?

Comment: After hours of trying to figure out why I couldn't deque a reusable cell I was so close to jumping out the window. Then, I stumbled across your post. I thought to myself "there is no way this could be the problem/fix" -- low and behold fixed the issue. Maybe I missed this in the release notes: "If you don't select a localization, you'll enter an infinite loop, but we won't tell you." THANK YOU!

Answer (score 5):

My solution was similar to styler1972's.

In my case, I was upgrading a combination Swift / Objective-C project from Swift 1.2 to Swift 2.0.  The app ran fine on iOS 9 prior to the upgrade to Swift 2.0.  After the upgrade to Swift 2.0 the app would enter an infinite loop when segueing from a Table View Cell Accessory Push to a View Controller.  Running the app in the simulator, then pausing it when caught in the infinite loop left me at [NSLocalizableString length] (which led me to this post).

My fix was to do the following.

- Remove the Main.storyboard file from the en.lproj directory.
- Remove the en.lproj directory, including the InfoPlist.strings file.
- Place Main.storyboard in the root project directory.
- Update the project to reflect the above changes.
- In the project settings under Info / Localization, remove all settings.
- Clean the build directory (for good measure).
- Clean the build (for good measure).
- Build and run.

Infinite loop no longer occurs.

Comment: EXACTLY! those conversion scripts are one of the *most* neglected things at apple.

Comment: Just spent 2 hours wondering why "dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier" was broken on 1 table view but not another. Thanks for this tip, worked for me to change the localization setting on that storyboad.

Comment: These steps above worked for me too. Good grief, I wasted a whole day and and a half on this! I really appreciate the info. No way I would have found this on my own.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to backup your project files to restore the localization files later on.

- In Project Settings, Localizations, remove all localizations except the project development language(which was English for me).
- Clean and run. At this point you should not see the error anymore.
- Add the localizations you removed above and restore the localizations from your backup.

Answer (score 0):

use `dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier` instead of `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`

You are trying to load cell in viewForHeaderInSection which is also not correct.

**Edited:**

```
class HeaderSectionView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {

@IBOutlet var labelOne: UITextView!
@IBOutlet var labelTwo: UITextView!
@IBOutlet var textView: UITextView!

}
```

and

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    //hangs on the line below
    let headersection: HeaderSectionView = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier("SectionHeader") as! HeaderSectionView

    ...

    return headersection
}
```

Do not forget to register your HeaderSectionView as

```
tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "HeaderSectionView", bundle:nil), forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "SectionHeader")
```

Comment: That yields: `Cast from 'UITableViewHeaderFooterView?' to unrelated type 'HeaderSectionCell' always fails.`

Comment: Where are you registering you section header View (HeaderSectionCell)? can you show the code?

Comment: When i convert to a UITableViewHeaderFooter, I get a runtime exception.  I'm using storyboard so I dont have to explicitly register.  However, this is working in other places in the app, so im not sure that converting is the appropriate course of action

Comment: I think you are dragging a UITableViewCell on your tableView for the sectionHeaderView which might sometimes work but I recommend to have a separate xib with a single UIView and attach your HeaderSectionView class with that view and then register your headerFooterView nib explicitly from code.