# Navigated my obj C code from Xcode 6.4 to Xcode 7(stable version) and app hangs when I try to push a view controller

Tags: objective-c, ios9, xcode7

Navigated my code from Xcode 6.4 to Xcode 7(stable version) and app hangs when I try to push a particular view controller. The code works perfectly fine in Xcode 6.5 iOS 9 but hangs in Xcode 7 iOS 9. The CPU usage reaches up to 90% and the app just freezes, nothing happens.

The controller being pushed has a `UITableViewController` with each cell having a `UITextView` and a `UILabel`. All other controllers work fine. I am using storyboard in my app.

Comment: Pause your app in the debugger when it freezes and see what's happening on various threads, especially the main one.

Comment: Thanks @PhillipMills. Your tip and this thread from stack exchange helped me reach the solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32593649/tableview-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier-causes-app-to-hang

Answer (score 0):

The UITextView in the cells had a non-empty text attribute set in the Xib. Removing that text value worked for me.
To make it work with the text value, I had to select 'English' under 'Localization' in File Inspector. By default, only 'Base' was selected.